# Can't work out what's wrong with this syntax

Tags: python-2.7

Very basic stuff here, but only been programming a week

We have a list of tasks to complete and of them is to:

Odd Even
Write a program that asks the user to enter an integer then decide if it is odd or even.

So far I've written

```
if var5%==0:
    print "Your number is even"
else:
    print "your number is odd"
```

But it says your syntax is incorrect here: '=' (the first equals)

Can anyone explain why? I don't have another lab session till next week

Answer (score 2):

The modulus operator, `%`, requires an argument on either side. You've only supplied the left argument. Try:

```
if var5 % 2 == 0:
```

Comment: Thats great it worked perfectly thanks! if you don't mind what does the '2' do apart from provide an argument? why 2? Thanks again.

Comment: `2` is the divisor. Since you are trying to determine odd and even numbers. `var5 % 2` translates to "what is the remainder of `var5` when divided by `2`. And you compare that remainder to `0`, since any even number divided by `2` will leave a remainder of `0`. Another thing to note `==` is comparison operator, while `=` is assignment operator in most languages. Be careful with that, so you don't assign a value when you are trying to compare values :)